# VIEW MODAL UPDATE IN ASP.NET MVC and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view, which shows a list of items consumed in a div and other details of a complaint in another div. Now, these items consumed div can have multiple records against a complaint. How to add new records and then refresh the div while still showing the original view. How to work around the problem. I did try to use modal popup but after submission and record update in the table, it's still showing the modal, whereas it needs to refresh the view itself.

This join view has edit option to set status, which leads to the problem view mentioned above.

In the status set view , i have multiple data such as id etc. in one div, Another div which contains the list of materials consumed so far. This div where consumption details are loaded as a list needs to be updated , as in new records to be updated and the updated view should be generated.

I need to dynamically add new material in the other div based on dropdown selection(hide/Show). and after submission, the tables needs to be updated.

```
public ActionResult StatusEdit(int id, int statuscode, string statusaction, int regid, short appid, short dep, short com )
{
        DisplayEC dn = new DisplayEC();
        DbAccess da = new DbAccess();
        dn.ComplnId = com;
        dn.JobC = id;
        ///dn.MatId = mat;
        ///dn.StDate = sdate;
        dn.DeptCode = dep;
        dn.Appid = appid;
        dn.statcode = statuscode;
        dn.statacn = statusaction;
        dn.Regid = regid;
        dn.JbStsDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        dn.DeptCode = Convert.ToByte(Session["departmentno"]);
        dn.ListJobStatus = new List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>();
        dn.ListJobStatus = da.GetAllJobStatus(dn.DeptCode, appid);
        dn.ListJobHistory = new List<JobStatus>();
        dn.ListJobMaterials = new List<DispJobMaterial>();
        dn.JobCode = dn.JobC.ToString();

        if ((dn.DeptCode > 0) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dn.JobCode)))
        {
            dn.ListJobHistory = da.GetJobStatusHistory(dn.DeptCode, dn.Appid, Convert.ToInt32(dn.JobC));
            dn.ListJobMaterials = da.GetMaterialsConsumed(dn.DeptCode, Convert.ToByte(dn.Appid), Convert.ToInt32(dn.JobC));
        }

        dn.ListMaterials = new List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>();
        dn.ListMaterials = da.GetMaterialsByUserType(dn.DeptCode, dn.Appid, "DEPTUSER");

        return View(dn);
}
```

View:

```
@using System.Web.Helpers
@model EC.ViewModels.DisplayEC
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout1.cshtml";
}
<br />
<br />
<a style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 30px; color:darkblue" title="Home" class="fa fa-home pull-left" href="@Url.Action("JoinView", "Admin")"></a>
<a style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 30px; color:darkblue" title="Log Out" class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right" href="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")"></a>
<br /><br />
<h4 class="display-4" style="display: inline;">JOBCODE ::  <span style="color:red">@Model.JobCode</span></h4>
<div class="mt-5">
    @*@using (Html.BeginForm("StatusEdit", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "StatusEdit", @class = "", role = "form" }))*@
    @using (Html.BeginForm("StatusEdit", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.JobC)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.JobCode)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DeptCode)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Appid)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.statcode)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.statacn)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Regid)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.JbStsDate)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Regid)
        @*@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.JobStatusCode)*@
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ComplnId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MatId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.StDate)
        <div>
            @if (TempData["notice"] != null)
            {
                <h4 class="alert alert-danger" id="successMessage">@TempData["notice"]</h4>
            }

        </div>
        <table class="table table-borderless" style="width:100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:50%">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header bg-secondary"><span style="font-weight:bold;color:white">JOB STATUS</span></div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <table class="table table-borderless" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width:30%">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.JobStatusCode, new { @class = "control-label label_text" })
                                                    <div>
                                                        @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.JobCode))
                                                        {
                                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.JobStatusCode, new SelectList(Model.ListJobStatus.ToList().Where(x => x.Value != "1").Where(x => x.Value != "2").Where(x => x.Value != "3").Where(x => x.Value != "6").Where(x => x.Value != "7").Where(x => x.Value != "5").ToList(), "Value", "Text", Model.JobStatusCode), new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "true", id = "ddlCategory" })
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.JobStatusCode, new SelectList(Model.ListJobStatus.ToList().Where(x => x.Value != "1").Where(x => x.Value != "2").Where(x => x.Value != "3").Where(x => x.Value != "6").Where(x => x.Value != "7").Where(x => x.Value != "5").ToList(), "Value", "Text", Model.JobStatusCode), new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddlCategory" })
                                                        }
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.JobStatusCode)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:20%">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.JbStsDate, new { @class = "control-label label_text" })
                                                    <div>
                                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.JbStsDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.JbStsDate)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:30%">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.JobStatusRemark, new { @class = "control-label label_text" })
                                                    <div>
                                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.JobStatusRemark, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.JobStatusRemark)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:20%">
                                                <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 30px;">
                                                    <button id="btnAddSts" type="button" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-info pull-left"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>&nbsp;Add Status</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table id="JbStsHtry" class="table table-responsive-md table-hover" style="width:100%">
                                    <tbody>
                                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListJobHistory.Count; i++)
                                        {
                                            <tr class="h-divider_sts">
                                                <td style="width:40%">
                                                    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ListJobHistory[i].StatusText)</span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width:20%">
                                                    <span>@Model.ListJobHistory[i].StatusDate.ToShortDateString()</span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width:30%">
                                                    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ListJobHistory[i].StatusRemarks)</span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width:10%">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:50%" id="Other">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header bg-secondary">
                                <span style="font-weight:bold;color:white">Material Consumed</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <table class="table table-borderless table-responsive-md" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr style="width:20%">
                                            <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.JobMaterialId, new { @class = "control-label label_text" })</th>
                                            <th> @Html.LabelFor(x => x.MatrlQty, new { @class = "control-label label_text" })</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width:40%">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    @*@Html.LabelFor(x => x.JobMaterialId, new { @class = "control-label label_text" })*@
                                                    <div>
                                                        @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.JobCode))
                                                        {
                                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.JobMaterialId, new SelectList(Model.ListMaterials, "Value", "Text", Model.JobMaterialId), new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "true" })
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.JobMaterialId, new SelectList(Model.ListMaterials, "Value", "Text", Model.JobMaterialId), new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                        }
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.JobMaterialId)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:30%">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    @*@Html.LabelFor(x => x.MatrlQty, new { @class = "control-label label_text" })*@
                                                    <div>
                                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MatrlQty, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.MatrlQty)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:30%">
                                                <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 30px;">
                                                    <button id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-info pull-left"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>&nbsp;Add Material</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                @*<table id="JbMatrl" class="table table-responsive-md table-hover" style="width:100%">*@
                                <table id="JbMatrl" class="table table-responsive-md table-hover" style="width:100%">
                                    <tbody>
                                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListJobMaterials.Count; i++)
                                        {
                                            <tr class="h-divider_sts">
                                                <td style="width:50%">
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ListJobMaterials[i].MaterialText)
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width:50%">
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ListJobMaterials[i].MaterialQty)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:50%" id="Other2">
                      
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 30px;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-left"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>&nbsp;Submit</button>
        </div>
    }
</div>
<br />
\\\\\\\\
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ddlCategory").change(function () {
                var e = document.getElementById("ddlCategory");
                var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
                if (value == "Assignment Cancelled") {
                    $('#Other').hide();
                    $('#Other2').show();
                } else {
                    $('#Other').show();
                    $('#Other2').hide();
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: On submit button click  in Material Consumption i need to add new materials . As in select from material type from dropdown and qty in textbox. after submit, this entered data should appear in the table below. later on submit button click at the bottom of the view, it should go to the post method for updating. there are multiple conditions as well in the view. if left div dropdown is selected as "Repaired", it will show the material consumed div else it will not show.